# Excel Chart dynamic charting throungh order form

Tags: excel

I am trying to build a chart from an order form in excel. I have built the order form and linked the chart to the form.

When I update my order form the chart should automatically change but currently the chart does not change when I add data to the order form.

I have searched everything on google and stackoverflow but I am not able to find any solution. I am new to Excel.

[image]